# How can I override inline styles with external CSS?

Tags: css

I have markup that uses inline styles, but I don't have access to change this markup. How do I override inline styles in a document using only CSS? I don't want to use jQuery or JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<div style="font-size: 18px; color: red;">
    Hello World, How Can I Change The Color To Blue?
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
   color: blue; 
   /* This Isn't Working */
}
```

Comment: Also see [CSS Cascade order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#complete_cascade_order)

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The only way to override inline style is by using `!important` keyword beside the CSS rule. The following is an example of it.

```css
div {
        color: blue !important;
       /* Adding !important will give this rule more precedence over inline style */
    }
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 18px; color: red;">
    Hello, World. How can I change this to blue?
</div>
```

> Important Notes:
>
> - **Using `!important` is not considered as a good practice**. Hence, you should avoid both `!important` and inline style.
> - Adding the `!important` keyword to any CSS rule lets the rule **forcefully precede over all the other CSS rules** for that element.
> - It even **overrides the inline styles** from the markup.
> - **The only way to override is by using another `!important` rule**, declared either with higher CSS specificity in the CSS, or equal CSS specificity later in the code.
> - **Must Read - [CSS Specificity by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)**

Comment: well that style part it up to him actually it is not necessary that he is using only for overriding the inline css

Comment: i know but the same i am saying !important will only increase the score for specific property, he may be using other properties (not for overriding) in the some block

Comment: Why is !important bad practice?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin because you cannot override that later if you need for any special case

Comment: Not inline, no, but inline is also bad practice. You can override !important in general by just having another !important later in the stylesheet. I think the real problem here is the OP shouldn't be using inline styles!

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin I agree inline styles should also be avoided, But the question was not that.

Comment: Yes, fair point; though oftentimes the specific question asked doesn't address the underlying problem. E.g. my own question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758073/when-inserting-data-from-a-query-to-a-table-does-the-query-run-for-each-record - where the answer was basically "yes", but the solution was entirely different.

Comment: @BFWebAdmin the problem is that you sometimes dont have a choice. for example the "badge" from the new invisible recaptcha can be styled but has partially inline styles so you have to override them either like this or by js and a prefer a pure CSS solution.

Comment: but this way it breaks the font icons for instance font-awsome

Comment: `!important` reads `not important` to me. Very confusing, but does work and sometimes there is a 3rd party element that has written itself into the page and this is the only way.

Answer (score 39):

`inline-styles` in a document have the highest priority, so for example say if you want to change the color of a `div` element to `blue`, but you've an `inline style` with a `color` property set to `red`

```
<div style="font-size: 18px; color: red;">
   Hello World, How Can I Change The Color To Blue?
</div>
```

```css
div {
   color: blue; 
   /* This Won't Work, As Inline Styles Have Color Red And As 
      Inline Styles Have Highest Priority, We Cannot Over Ride 
      The Color Using An Element Selector */
}
```

So, Should I Use jQuery/Javascript? - Answer Is **NO**

We can use `element-attr` CSS Selector with `!important`, note, `!important` is important here, else it won't over ride the inline styles..

```
<div style="font-size: 30px; color: red;">
    This is a test to see whether the inline styles can be over ridden with CSS?
</div>
```

```css
div[style] {
   font-size: 12px !important;
   color: blue !important;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eZfwd/)

> Note: Using `!important` ONLY will work here, but I've used
>   `div[style]` selector to specifically select `div` having `style`
>   attribute

Comment: So, Should I Use Inline styles? - Answer Is **NO** :-)

Comment: "So, Should I Use jQuery/Javascript? - Answer Is NO" 
Why? If I'm working in an environment (such as Sharepoint) where inline styles are added to elements by an uncontrollable entity why wouldn't I use Jquery to remove the offending inline styles so my sites external theme shows through? Seems a more precesion solution than blasting !important on a trait I might want to override in a specific instance later.

Comment: @Neberu - Because JS can be blocked/turned off at the browser. Using `!important` cannot AFAIK.

Comment: also js is imo bad in general, I mean do you open executable files sent by you from an unknown person? I guess not, but a browser does this with each click

Answer (score 12):

You can easily override inline style except inline `!important` style

so

```
<div style="font-size: 18px; color: red;">
    Hello World, How Can I Change The Color To Blue?
</div>

div {
   color: blue !important; 
   /* This will  Work */
}
```

but if you have

```
<div style="font-size: 18px; color: red !important;">
    Hello World, How Can I Change The Color To Blue?
</div>

div {
   color: blue !important; 
   /* This Isn't Working */
}
```

now it will be `red` only .. and you can not override it

Comment: How is this any different from the answers that were added months before?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin This answer is describing the behaviour when the inline style has `!important`, a point not covered by any of the other answers. This may not be a completely stand-alone answer but this is different to the other answers provided.

Comment: but then again using an inline style with important is really overkill since it by default has the highest priority anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div style="background: red;">
    The inline styles for this div should make it red.
</div>

div[style] {
   background: yellow !important;
}
```

Below is the link for more details:
http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: Downvote because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

used `!important` in CSS property

```
<div style="color: red;">
    Hello World, How Can I Change The Color To Blue?
</div>
```

```
div {
        color: blue !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`!important`, after your CSS declaration.

```css
div {
   color: blue !important; 

   /* This Is Now Working */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
 color : blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="color : red">
  hello
</div>
```