# How can I override an inline CSS rule using an external file?

Tags: html, css

How can I override an inline CSS rule with using an external stylesheet file?

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="mydiv" style="background:#000"> lorem ipsom</div>
```

I want to change the background color using CSS. This is my CSS code:

```
.mydiv {background:#f00; color: #000;}
```

But this is not working, but I this is possible.

Is there a way to change the background color in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very simple. Use `!important` after your rule style. Here is the example:

```
.mydiv {background:#f00 !important; color: #000;}
```

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/msJxL/

And for Internet Explorer, check out *[How To Create an IE-Only Stylesheet | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)*.

Comment: also plz let me know show can i change color in a single style shee, the link u send me is for external ie css which i have to attach in my document but the problem is i cannot edit my html document

Comment: Check your spelling @Vipul ... it's "simple" not simpale... since it's the accepted answer I thought it would be nice if it was cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

Inline style is treated as having a higher [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than any rule-set.

The only ways to override it are to change it on the element or use [an `!important` rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules).

`!important` rules are a sledgehammer of a solution and only work once (if you want to override again, you are stuck; there is no such thing as a double !important rule), so changing the style attribute value (preferably removing it entirely in favour of a stylesheet) is the best option.

If you really want to use `!important` then the syntax is:

```
.mydiv {
    background:#f00 !important;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `!important` for this. It will override other CSS. Try the following code:

```
.mydiv {background:#f00 !important; color: #000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.mydiv {
     background: #f00 !important;
     /* This will increase the rule score */
     color: #000;
}
```

Detailed information: Stack Overflow question *[How can I override inline styles with external CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813220/override-inline-css-with-external-stylesheet/16813263#16813263)*.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CSS attribute selector:

```
 <style>
     div[style] {
        background: blue !important;
     }
 </style>

 <div style="background: red;">
     The inline styles.
 </div>
```

Comment: Attribute selectors have nothing to do with this.