# When inserting data from a query to a table, does the query run for each record inserted?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm inserting data problematically into tables. When I do this from another table, it's swift, only slowed very slightly if there are a lot of records. Even then, it's a matter of seconds.

When I insert from a query to a table, it goes into minutes - roughly a minute for every 1,000 records inserted.

The source query itself, when just run as a select query, takes maybe 1 - 2 seconds. Is the query running for every record that's inserted? I'd hoped that it would run once for the whole data set. Or is there something else that's causing the function to run so slowly when compared to inserting "flat" data from another table.

The VBA I'm using is fairly innocuous:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT [Extra Value Concatenation].* _
INTO [" & strTableName & "] FROM [Extra Value Concatenation];"
```

and the source query is below - it uses [Allen Browne's Concatenate function](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html).

```
SELECT [Extra Fields - Fee Protection Insurance Concatenate].ContactID,
ConcatRelated('[Fee Protection Insurance]',
'[Extra Fields - Fee Protection Insurance Concatenate]',
'ContactID = ' & [ContactID]) 
AS [Fee Protection Insurance]
FROM [Extra Fields - Fee Protection Insurance Concatenate];
```

**EDIT: In answer to Fionnuala's comment, but I couldn't format it properly in the comments.**

Using fictional data, here's roughly what I want.

T1 contains client records.

```
ContactID    Name
1            Example Limited
2            Another Company Limited
```

T2 contains extra fields. ContactID is there as a foreign key, and may be duplicated if multiple records are held.

```
ContactID    FieldValue
1            Value 1
1            Value 2
2            Value 3
2            Value 4
2            Value 5
```

When I left join the tables, the duplicates from T2 show up, so I get

```
ContactID    Name                       FieldValue
1            Example Limited            Value 1
1            Example Limited            Value 2
2            Another Company Limited    Value 3
2            Another Company Limited    Value 4
2            Another Company Limited    Value 5
```

when what I want is

```
ContactID    Name                       FieldValue
1            Example Limited            Value 1; Value 2
2            Another Company Limited    Value 3; Value 4; Value 5
```

Hence concatenating the data in a temporary table seemed like a good idea, but is slowing everything down. Is there another way I should be looking at my query?

Comment: You using user defined functions (UDF) ConcatRelated, so the UDF runs for each record, otherwise, usually not.

Comment: Thanks @Remou - Yes, I am, that's the Concatenate bit. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Other than avoiding UDFs if you need speed, no, there is no way around. Why do you wish to concatenate? It is nearly always a bad idea.

Comment: @Remou - I have two tables I want to join, one of which doesn't allow duplicates in the ID, and the other of which does (because it holds multiple values for each record). When left joining them, the duplicates in table 2 show up in the query even though there are no duplicates in table 1. Concatenating the data in table 2 (which is temporary, so no long term damage done to the data) seemed like a good way around this, because then DISTINCT ignores the duplicate rows (which are now all identical). Should I look at the whole query a different way perhaps?

Comment: Probably, do you have sample data and required result?

Comment: @Remou - Thanks, I've edited the question to also include the underlying problem, as I couldn't format it properly in the comments.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin Do you get a performance improvement by creating the table first and then converting to an "append query": `INSERT 
INTO YourNewTable FROM [Extra Value Concatenation];`

Comment: @HansUp - That's what I tried originally - it takes almost exactly the same amount of time - the current method was 3 seconds faster, but that could be down to any number of things.

Comment: In that case, unless you have a specific upper limit of records to concatenate, I think you are stuck with slow, but the question remains, why not have separate records? What do you do with the data after it is returned? There may be a case for lateral thinking.

Comment: The intention is to generate a mailing list. All the contact and address data etc is in the T1 and the fields we'll filter on are in T2, so multiple records doesn't work in this circumstance. Thanks though - also, if you want to put an answer of "It's the UDF that's causing the issue", I'll happily accept it as it's the answer to my original question.

Comment: I have added an answer, but I am not quite happy, I wonder of a set of subqueries would allow your filtered mailmerge?

Comment: Am going to have a bit of a think about it at home - I suspect that maybe concatenating the final results of the mailing list would work just as well but haven't tested it yet. Thanks for your help today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a user defined function (UDF) ConcatRelated, so the UDF runs for each record, otherwise, usually Access SQL works in the normal way.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a pretty basic module that should accomplish this for you very quickly compared to your current process.  Note you will need to re-name your project to something other than "Database" on the project navigation pane for this to work

I have assumed that table1 and table2 are the same as you have above
table3 is simply a list of all records in table 1 with a blank "FieldValues" field to add
the required "value1, value2" etc.  This should result in Table3 being populated with your desired result

IMPORANT: For anyone using recordset .edit and .update functions make sure you remove record level locking in the access options menu, it can be found under the "client settings" section of Access options, failing to do so will cause extreme bloating of your file as access will not drop record locks until you compact and repair the database.  This may cause your database to become un-recoverable once it hits the 2gb limit for windows.

```
Function addValueField()

'Declarations
Dim db As Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim qry As String
Dim value As String
Dim recordcount as Long


Set db = CurrentDb()

'Open a select query that is a join of table 1 and table 2
'I have made Contact ID a foreign key in the second table
qry = "SELECT Table1.[Contact ID], Table1.Name, Table2.FieldValue FROM Table1 INNER     JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[Contact ID] = Table2.[Contact ID(FK)] ORDER BY [Contact ID];"

Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(qry, dbOpenDynaset)


'Table 3 was filled with each record from table1, with a 3rd "Field Value" field to
'be filled with your Value 1, Value 2 etc.
qry = "SELECT * FROM Table3 ORDER BY [Contact ID]"

Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(qry, dbOpenDynaset)

'Ensure you have enough file locks to process records
recordcount = rs1.recordcount
DAO.DBEngine.SetOption DAO.dbMaxLocksPerFile, recordcount + 1000

rs1.MoveFirst
rs2.MoveFirst

'Here we test to see if "Name" is the same in both recordsets, if it is, add the       FieldValue
'to the FieldValue in Table3, otherwise move to the next record in table 3 and compare    again


Do While Not rs1.EOF
    If IsNull(rs2![FieldValue]) = True Then
        If rs2![FieldValue] = "" Then
            rs2.Edit
            rs2![FieldValue] = rs1![FieldValue]
            rs2.Update
            rs1.MoveNext
        Else
            rs2.Edit
            rs2![FieldValue] = rs2![FieldValue] & "; " & rs1![FieldValue]
            rs2.Update
            rs1.MoveNext
        End If
    Else
        rs2.MoveNext
    End If
    Loop
rs1.close
rs2.close
db.close
set db = nothing
set rs1 = nothing
set rs2 = nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have to downvote this one. The repeated `.Edit` and `.Update` operations on the target recordset bloat the database tremendously. When I tried it on my million-row test table (48MB) your routine exploded the .accdb file to 2GB and rendered the database unusable. By comparison, the ConcatRelated() make-table approach did take just over a minute to complete, but the database only grew from 48MB to around 90MB. With a volume of data large enough for ConcatRelated() to significantly hinder performance this is not a very good workaround. :(

Comment: @GordThompson I was a little confused as to why you would experience so much record bloat... I regularly process tables of that size with none. Then I remembered you need to disable record level locking to ensure access doesen't store all the record locks in memory, this will also greatly reduce processing time. Un-check the "open databases using record level locking" option under "client settings" of access and you should be able to run this without issue. If you are willing to try this again I do believe this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, un-checking "Open databases with record-level locking" avoided the issue, and the approach proved to be significantly faster than the ConcatRelated() make-table method. Please edit your answer to add that configuration tweak and I'll remove my downvote. (The tweak really is important because once a database file hits the 2GB "wall" it can be **very** difficult to recover.)

Comment: Hi @pegicity - Thanks for your help on this. Because I'd used fictional data and very simplified structure, had to do a little bit of work to fit it into my database, but really set me off on the right course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Building on pegicity's answer, my eventual code was:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub Concatenate(strTableToConcatenate As String, strFieldToConcatenate As String, strIDField As String)

Dim rsSource As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsDestination As DAO.Recordset
Dim qry As String
Dim strSourceTable As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strFieldName As String
Dim strValue As String
Dim intConcatenateID As Integer
Dim intSortID As Integer

strSourceTable = strTableToConcatenate & " (Concatenate)" 'Creates a duplicate copy of the table to be concatenated and empties the original table'
DeleteTable (strSourceTable)
DoCmd.CopyObject , strSourceTable, acTable, strTableToConcatenate
qry = "DELETE FROM [" & strTableToConcatenate & "]"
CurrentDb.Execute (qry)

qry = "ALTER TABLE [" & strTableToConcatenate & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & strFieldToConcatenate & "] memo" 'Changes the DataType of the field to be concatenated to Memo, as the result may be considerably longer than the original data'
CurrentDb.Execute (qry)

i = 0
intCurrentID = 0

qry = "SELECT * FROM [" & strSourceTable & "] ORDER BY [" & strIDField & "], [" & strFieldToConcatenate & "]"
Set rsSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qry, dbOpenDynaset)
qry = "SELECT * FROM [" & strTableToConcatenate & "]"
Set rsDestination = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qry, dbOpenDynaset)

For Each fld In rsSource.Fields 'Finds the column number of the fields you are sorting by and concatenating from your source table.'
    strFieldName = rsSource.Fields(i).Name
    If strFieldName = strFieldToConcatenate Then
        intConcatenateID = i
    ElseIf strFieldName = strIDField Then
        intSortID = i
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next

If rsSource.recordcount <> 0 Then

    rsSource.MoveFirst
    intCurrentID = rsSource.Fields(intSortID).Value
    strConcatenateValue = ""

    While Not rsSource.EOF 'The source recordset is sorted by your designated sort field, so any duplicates of that field will be next to each other. If the row below has the same id as the row above, the sub continues to build the concatenated value. If the row changes, it adds the concatenated value to the destination record set.'

       If intCurrentID = rsSource.Fields(intSortID).Value Then

            strConcatenateValue = strConcatenateValue & "," & rsSource.Fields(intConcatenateID).Value
            rsSource.MoveNext

       Else
            rsDestination.AddNew

            i = 0

            If Len(strConcatenateValue) > 0 Then
                strConcatenateValue = Right(strConcatenateValue, Len(strConcatenateValue) - 1)
            End If

            For Each fld In rsSource.Fields
                strFieldName = rsSource.Fields(i).Name
                If strFieldName = strFieldToConcatenate Then
                     strValue = strConcatenateValue
                ElseIf strFieldName = strIDField Then
                    strValue = intCurrentID
                Else
                    strValue = rsSource.Fields(i).Value
                End If
                rsDestination.Fields(strFieldName) = "" & strValue & ""
                i = i + 1
            Next

            rsDestination.Update
            intCurrentID = rsSource.Fields(intSortID).Value
            strConcatenateValue = ""

       End If

     Wend

End If

rsSource.Close
rsDestination.Close
Set rsSource = Nothing
Set rsDestination = Nothing

End Sub
```