# Can you use a variable for the Field name when using AddNew to a record set?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, recordset

I'm using a DAO recordset to update a table because of problems enocuntered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758073/when-inserting-data-from-a-query-to-a-table-does-the-query-run-for-each-record).

This works fine when I know the name of the field I'm updating, e.g.:

```
rs2.AddNew
rs2![ContactID] = rs.Fields(0).Value
rs2![Fee Protection Insurance] = "" & strValue & ""
rs2.Update
```

works perfectly.

However, the field that I'm trying to update won't always have the same name, so I attempted to use a variable here too, expecting it to evaluate and be equivilent to the above code:

```
rs2.AddNew
rs2![ContactID] = rs.Fields(0).Value
rs2!["strFieldName"] = "" & strValue & ""
rs2.Update
```

but it tells me that item's not in the collection, even when strFieldName is set to Fee Protection Insurance.

I've tried this various ways, including:

```
rs2![" & strFieldName & "] = "" & strValue & ""

rs2![strFieldName] = "" & strValue & ""

rs2!["" & strFieldName & ""] = "" & strValue & ""

rs2![cStr(strFieldName)] = "" & strValue & ""
```

none of which work.

Am I going about this the wrong way, or am I attempting something impossible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use this one:

```
rs2.Fields(strFieldName) = "" & strValue & ""
```

Comment: Pretty much the only combination of punctuation I hadn't tried, and it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution

```
rs2.Fields(strFieldName) = "" & strValue & ""
```

can be shortened to

```
rs2(strFieldName) = "" & strValue & ""
```

Answer (score -3):

Very Simple answer YES you can access VARIABLE FIELD NAMES.
For example: 
I have a form that has multiple buttons... Here's how to name and access them.

Name each Button on your form: MyButton(1) through MyButton(X)
The code places the number on each button by changing the caption.
stButton is the string value of the Button name

X=10

For Btn = 1 To X

Set StButton = Me("MyButton" & "(" & Btn & ")")

StButton.Caption = Btn

Next Btn

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question at all.