# How to override Inline Style CSS?

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

I have tried the div[style]
The problem is this is not the only element with inline styles

**The HTML**

```
<input class="button cool-button" style="float: right !important color:blue" value="Hello" name="hello">
<input class="button cool-button" style="float: right !important color:blue" value="World" name="hello">
<input class="button cool-button" style="float: right !important  color:blue" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

*I am targeting the submit button*

**This is how I attempted to over-ride the css on my external style sheet...**

```
input.button .cool-button[style] [value="Submit"] [name="submit"] {
    float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You're targeting children, not the same element when you use spaces.

Comment: All you need is `input.button.cool-button { float: none !important; }`

Comment: Do not use inline styling, use only css to override.

Comment: Along with your CSS there are also syntax errors in the inline styles. If that's what your HTML really looks like, then there's actually nothing to override since the inline style attributes are completely malformed.

Comment: @user3466437 Thanks for that! But no it is not the actual HTML

Comment: You should not be using inline style, it is awful.

Comment: Currently the inline styles are using `important!`, you might mean `!important`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I override inline styles with external CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813220/how-can-i-override-inline-styles-with-external-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your inputs have the `!important` syntax in the inline style, than that will take precedence over any css/styles to that element so you wont be able to `float:none`.

```
<input class="button cool-button" style="float: right !important; color:blue" value="Hello" name="hello">
```

however, if your inputs do not have `!important`, you can do the following

```css
input.button.cool-button { 
    float: none !important; 
}
```

```html
<input class="button cool-button" style="float: right ; color:blue" value="Hello" name="hello">
<input class="button cool-button" style="float: right ; color:blue" value="World" name="hello">
<input class="button cool-button" style="float: right ; color:blue" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

and the `float:none` in the css sheet will override the `float: right` that is inline

Comment: I thought so. Either way - is the syntax correct the way I selected multiple psuedo-classes?

Comment: @Mike the `[value=""]` and `[name=""]` selectors were correct, but i dont think `style` exists. also, as was stated before by Nit, you also have to get rid of the spaces in your selectors. spaces means children of element, no spaces means same element

Comment: @indubitablee: `style` refers to the style attribute. It's not any different from the value and name attributes.

Answer (score 2):

It is just one step process that you need to add

```
Element[style].button.cool-button{
float:left !important;
}
```

For Example based in your case

```
<input class="button cool-button" style="float: right ; color:blue" value="Hello" name="hello">
```

Create Custom.css file and add the following line of code

```
/*To override inline style sheet for 'Input' Element*/

input[style].button.cool-button{
float:left !important;
color:white !important;
}
```

Hope fully it will help someone!
Thank you 
Cheers 
Ishwor Khanal

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra extension:

```
input.button.cool-button.right{
  float: right;
}
```

And add the `right` class instead of the style to the input tags.

However use `clear: right` to cancel the floating.

Answer (score -1):

```
input.button.cool-button { 
    float: none !important; 
}
```

I hope this helps