# Override height of box in shiny dashboard and leaflet

Tags: css, r, height, shiny, dashboard

I created a dashboard using `shinyDashboard` and I have a map with `leaflet`. The `box` element used in shinyDashboard creates a fixed height of 400px for the map.

I would like the map to be `90vh` so that it covers most of the screen, and so I wrote this on the `UI` file:

```
tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css",'
                                            #geomap {
                                            height: 90vh;
                                            }
                                            ')),
                  box(title = "Geographical distribution",
                    leafletOutput("geomap")
                  )
                )
              )
      )
```

Now, when I inspect the page, I can see that the property was passed onto the `#geomap` id, but it is overridden for some reason

[image]!

Also, here is the node

[image].

I have overridden classes before successfully, so I don't understand how an ID can't be overridden. Any ideas?

Thank you!

EDIT: Here's an example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$geomap <- renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet(data) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")

  })
}

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Map distribution", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
                      )
                    ),


                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
                                fluidPage(
                                  fluidRow(
                                    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                                            .col-sm-6 {
                                                              width: 100%;
                                                              }
                                                              '))),
                                    box(title = "Geographical distribution",
                                        leafletOutput("geomap")
                                    )
                                    )
                                  )
                                )
                          )
                      )
                    )

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: have you tried applying !important to the css? height: 90vh !important;

Comment: You're trying to override an inline style which has higher precedence. See solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813220/how-can-i-override-inline-styles-with-external-css

Comment: @MrFlick , @Carlton Thank you, that did it. Although I really dislike having to use `!important` but I guess there is no other way to do it.

Comment: You could try `leafletOutput("geomap", height="90vh")` (and don't bother with the css tags in the head). You didn't make a reproducible example so it's not easy to test other possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick if I do that I get the error `"90vh" is not a valid CSS unit (e.g., "100%", "400px", "auto")` . Also, you are right about the example, so I provided a link to the code at the bottom ^

Comment: @MrFlick Also, what do you mean by "don't bother with the css tags in the head", is this a bad practice?

Comment: If the `height=` parameter worked then the header css would have been unnecessary or redundant. Maybe you can set `height=NA` or `height=NULL` to turn off the default 100%? I don't want to have to clone a repo to test. Its easier if you include a copy/paste-able example in the question itself. But the problem looks like the [htmltools::validateCssUnit](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/blob/08536e15b7e2e7c6c9f1aa7b2969ac4379f17e30/R/tags.R#L1369) function doesn't recognize "vh" units despite them being valid.

Comment: @MrFlick I have now added an example code. I understand what you mean about the head. Both `height=NA` and `height=NULL` cause the output to render a blank container.

Comment: I think that issue is not in the `ui` but in `server`. There is the fixed ration between leaflet longitute and latitute. Therefore, it display the full map. If you would like to zoom the map you can use `setView` or `fitBounds`. For example adding this in server `%>% setView(-71.0382679, 42.3489054, zoom = 1)` with zoom the map to all box.

Comment: @Vova I understand what you are saying, but that is not my question. My problem is not the map view, is the height of the container of the map, i.e. the `box` element. With your code the map fills the box, but the box is still only 400px tall.

Comment: @JotaSolano, yes i do understand the issue. But in my machine i can easily control the height and width of both leaflet and box. `fluidRow(
                                    box(title = "Geographical distribution",
                                        width = "100%",
                                        height = 500,
                                        leafletOutput("geomap", height = 250)
                                    )
                                    )` The thing is that when setting height you shall be careful using "%", with pixels it shall work