# !important is not overriding inline CSS

Tags: css

I have some inline CSS I can't change

```
<span style = "color: #404040; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 17px;">

stuff

</span>
```

and it is overriding my external CSS. I tried putting !important

```
.product-description 
{
  font-family:wide latin !important;
}
```

[but it had no effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KZK9.png)

If I go to inspect element and delete the style attribute, my external CSS [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14f2l.png)

Comment: @HunterTurner not true. `!important` is the only way to override inline styles from a stylesheet, [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/n6vphe2d/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813220/how-can-i-override-inline-styles-with-external-css).

Comment: @hungerstar Ah, sorry. I was thinking that the inline styles were `!important` as well. Misread that.

Comment: If the font name is Wide Latin try enclosing it in quotes `font-family: "Wide Latin" !important;` and see if that has any effect.

Comment: @hungerstar The only thing I have access to is the CSS file.

Comment: @RobertC It didn't work

Comment: @abcdefg4321 see my updated answer.

Comment: Can you show us more code, specifically enough to show where `. product-description` is in relation to the `span` you've displayed above.  You may need to adjust your selector to be something along the lines of `.product-description span { }` or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update 1

OP mentioned they only have access to the CSS file.

In this case, you will need to change your CSS selector up a bit but is still doable. The example below has the class applied to the parent element of an element you'd like to change.

```css
.change p {
  color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="change">
  <p style="color: blue;">
    This is some text.
  </p>
</div>
```

You might have to get even more specific with your CSS selector if there are a lot of child elements to wade through when you hook into a CSS class selector. Try to hook into the CSS class selector that is the closest to the element you want to target.

```css
.change div p:nth-child(2) {
  color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="change">

  <p style="color: blue;">
    This is some text.
  </p>

  <div>

    <p style="color: green;">
      This is some text.
    </p>

    <p style="color: orange;">
      This is some text. (only change me)
    </p>

  </div>

</div>
```

#### Original Answer

My guess is that you're not applying the CSS class directly to the element you want changed as I do not see `.product-description` being applied to the example `<span>`.

Look at the two examples below.

1. I think you're attempting this one, class applied to outer element of the element you want changed. `<p>` would inherit the color of `.change` if `<p>` didn't have something with a higher specificity applied to it, like inline CSS or another CSS class.
2. Here we apply the class directly to the element we want changed, that way the specificity of `!important` can override the specificity of the inline CSS.

```css
.change {
  color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- #1 -->
<div class="change">
  <p style="color: green;">
    This is some text.
  </p>
</div>

<!-- #2 -->
<div>
  <p class="change" style="color: green;">
    This is some text.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `.product-description *` will apply the styles to **every** child element of `.product-description`.

Comment: @hungerstar you saying "You might have to get even more specific with you CSS selector" helped me! Thank you!

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks