# How to modify only via CSS a color already defined in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to modify a color in a text marked by the tag "U" with the color already defined in html.

It is so in html:

```html
<u> <font color="#0000c0">somente no seu e-commerce</font> </u>
```

I tried as follows in the css:

```
u {color: rgb (20,20,20)! important; }
```

but I do not accept the color, I believe that the fact is defined in the source code.

the important detail, I do not have access to modify the html, as it is generated by web software. all layout modification gotta be done ONLY by CSS.

Comment: Hi there, SO is English only, so please ask in English, or use [one of the language-specific SO variants](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name), probably you need this one: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: oh!.. sorry.. i'm new here.  i'll try there.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16813221/993547.

Comment: @PatrickHofman — No, it's a completely different issue. There's no inline style in this question.

Comment: @Quentin This does work though, as proposed in the dup: `font[color="red"] { color: blue; }`

Comment: The color of the font is controlled by the innermost tag `font` in your code. Your CSS sets the font color on the outer element `u` only. Use `u font {color: rgb (20,20,20)! important; }` instead. And just for completeness' sake, `font` tag has been deprecated since WW II.

Comment: Comments are not the place to put answers.

Comment: But still it is a duplicate. I just say the duplicate answer fixes the problem @Quentin

Comment: @PatrickHofman — It doesn't. Some code that was vaguely inspired by that answer fixes the problem, but that code is unnecessarily bloated, and the explanation on the answer is completely wrong for *this* question.

Comment: @Quentin I did not get the chance to choose answer or comment, since this question is on hold.

Comment: @connexo — So vote for it to be reopened and give an answer when it is. If a question is closed it shouldn't be answered, comments are not a way to bypass that rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is successfully changing the colour of the `<u>` element, but you can't see any effect because the `<font>` element does not have `color: inherit` (and there is no text outside of the `<font>`). It has its own colour and does not use the `<u>`'s colour at all.

To change that, you need to target the font element.

```css
font {
  color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
```

```html
<u> <font color="#0000c0">somente no seu e-commerce</font> </u>
```

There is no need for the rule to be `!important`. There's no CSS of a higher specificity to hammer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It works as follows: u> font {color: rgb(20,20,20) ! important; }
It worked.
thank you

Comment: dont work without `!important`. i tried. was needed insert `>` between elements.

Comment: @HarryCarvalho — I've edited a live demo into the question. It doesn't need `!important` or `>`. If your code does, then you have other code influencing it which you didn't include in your [mcve].

Comment: As I said above, my code was created by a software ( a web survey software, in ASP), an old software.  That generate a dirty code, full of tables, scripts and inline styles, maybe some is ovewriting. One more time, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The color of the font is controlled by the innermost tag `font` in your code. Your CSS sets the font color on the outer element `u` only. Use

`u font { color: rgb(20,20,20) }`

instead. Also notice that there cannot be any space between `rgb` and `20,20,20)`, also there may not be any space between `!` and `important`.

On top of that, `!important` is appparently not necessary here as CSS styles for color seem to beat the specificity of inline `color` attributes.

And just for completeness' sake, the `font` tag has been deprecated since WW II (or somewhere around that time ;) ).

```css
u font {
  color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
```

```html
<u><font color="#0000c0">somente no seu e-commerce</font> </u>
```

Comment: It works as follows: u> font {color: corDesejada! important; }
It worked.
thank you