# how to override properties defined in polymer using media queries

Tags: css, polymer, mpmediaquery

assume that we have declared a property named  height=""  which has a certain value, let say 200px.
I was wondering that is there a way that we could override this property using media queries in css?as far as I know, the inline properties has higher priority than the css styles.

this is the example code for such condition :

```
    @media (max-width:480px){

        custom-element{
            height: 50px;
        }
}
```

```
<body>
<custom-element height="200px">
</custom-element>
</body>
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `!important` will take give the external style precedence, and you can target the div with a style tag specifically like this:

```
custom-element[style] {
   height:50px !important;
}
```

It's good to avoid using `!important` as much as possible but it's one of the few ways to override an inline-style.

[Similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813220/how-can-i-override-inline-styles-with-external-css)

Comment: yeah we can use it, but it will make the important style the prime, for the whole queries and it cannot be used in a specific breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting attributes and inline styles confused. CSS happily overrides inline `height` attributes.

CSS

```
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Height is 100px -->
<img height="200px">
<!-- Height is 200px -->
<img style="height: 200px">
```

http://jsbin.com/juhuteviqi/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: this height attribute is only for predefined elements like img and it  has nothing to do with polymer element's attributes

Comment: Ah. In that case the `!important` flag is probably your best bet.