# js-mindmap CSS override background color from style sheet

Tags: css

Can't remember how to override the background in a css sheet in the html the a.node needs to be blue. In my html i have `style="background:blue"`Several examples on SO have have not solved this question - they are similar but not able to resolve.

My css page:

```
body {
background:black;
}
.js-mindmap-active a.node {
    background:red;
    border: 2px solid white;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;    
}
.js-mindmap-active a.node.active {
    padding:5px 10px !important;
    border-width:5px !important;
}
.js-mindmap-active a.node.activeparent {
    padding:5px 10px !important;
    border-width:5px !important;
    background:#8B0000;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://sample.com/">ALS</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank" style="background:blue">Chest Pain</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon linkedin">Shortness of Breath</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon facebook">Allergic Reaction</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="icon twitter" title="goo">Diabetic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">STEMI</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon twitter" title="9">ACS</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon twitter" title="13">STEMI</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="A">Treatment</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" title="C">Protocol</a></li> 
              </ul>
            </li> 
        </ul>
        </li>


        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: you can just put `background:blue;` in the stylesheet targetting the item... add a class to it maybe

Comment: Try this ----  background-color:blue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override inline styles with external CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813220/how-can-i-override-inline-styles-with-external-css)

Comment: not a duplicate since resuts are not productive.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `!important` at end of css property:

```
background:blue !important;
```

Important will avoid all cascading css

Comment: still not overriding color?