# Hide inline CSS on mobile device

Tags: css, inline

I want to hide inline css background image of a paragraph tag to be hidden on mobile devices. How should I achieve this?

```
  <div class="items-body">
         <p
         style={{ background: `url('${item.image.childImageSharp.fluid.src}') no-repeat right 30px` }}
         ><Content source={item.sectiontext} /> </p>
   </div>
```

I tried this in a separate CSS file where items-body CSS is defined but no change

```
   @media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .items-body p{
     background: URL ('');
    }
}
```

or

```
   @media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .items-body p{
     background: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I override inline styles with external CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813220/how-can-i-override-inline-styles-with-external-css)

Comment: yes, it worked, I forgot to add "!important"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the inline style with `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Use !important

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .items-body p{
     background: none !important ;
    }
}
```